# jqGrid - vertical scrollbar not showing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, scrollbar

I'm working on jquery jqgrid plugin. In this grid, I have 1,000,000 records with `scroll: 1` option. and also I have `rowNum: 10` option in my grid. But just first 10 row displayed in the grid and vertical scroll bar is missing. in the caption, I have "display 1-10 from 1,000,000" string. this means that the total number calculation is correct, but I don't know why scroll bar is missing. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

**EDIT:** My jqGrid version is: `4.6.0`. Here is my javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            var colModel = [
                {name: "id", width: 200, align: "center", searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}, hidden: true, hiddenlg: true},
                {name: "ordernumber", width: 200, align: "center", searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}},
                {name: "customer.fname", width: 200, align: "center", searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}},
                {name: "customer.lname", width: 200, align: "center", searchoptions: {clearSearch: false}},
            ];
            $("#list").jqGrid({
                url: "/orders/listGrid",
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: "POST",
                colNames: ["", "1", "2", "3"],
                colModel: colModel,
                pager: "#pager",
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                viewrecords: true,
                multiSort: false,
                gridview: true,
                autoencode: true,
                shrinkToFit: false,
                autowidth: true,
                scroll: 1,
                direction: "rtl",
                height: 230,
                caption: "Test",
                hidegrid: false,
                ajaxGridOptions: {
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                },
                serializeGridData: function(data) {
                    return JSON.stringify(data);
                },

            });
        });
```

And this is my html code:

```
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Comment: **Do you specified explicitly `height` option in the grid with some value other as `"auto"` and `"100%"`?** Try to specify `height: 230` for example, which is enough to show 10 rows of the standard text. Could you post more information about what you do? Which version of jqGrid you use? Is the problem exist only in some specific version of jqGrid?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will update my question and add extra information to it. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem exist probably because you use very large number of rows and the current implementation of virtual scrolling don't allows to display such number of rows. The exact restriction of the maximal number of rows depend on the web browser which you use. Look at [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/virtual-scrolling-in-ie-cand-display-more-as-about-66700-rows) which I posted some years before. See [the post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/ru-ru/870b5c5d-ed26-4b03-9c17-438b779b264b/what-is-the-maximum-height-of-div-in-internet-explorer) additionally.

The problem is the following. jqGrid uses div outside of the grid and try to set its height to the value `parseInt(ts.p.records,10) * rowHeight` (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L1855)) where `rowHeight` is 23px. So jqGrid will try to set `height` to `23000000px` in your case, but it will don't change the `height` value and one will see no vertical scroll bar.

One can try to make some tricks like the usage of the code like

```
jsonReader: {
    records: function (obj) {
        // return not so large value of records
        return Math.min(66692, obj.records);
    }
},
loadComplete: function (data) {
    var $self = $(this), p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        numberFormat = $.fmatter.util.NumberFormat || $.fmatter.NumberFormat,
        fmt = $.jgrid.formatter.integer || {},
        from = numberFormat(parseInt(p.page,10), fmt),
        to = numberFormat((parseInt(p.page,10)-1)*parseInt(p.rowNum,10) + p.reccount, fmt),
        total = numberFormat(parseInt(data.records,10), fmt); // use correct value

    // fix the displayed row numbers
    $(".ui-paging-info", p.pager)
        .html($.jgrid.format(p.recordtext, from, to, total));
}
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/hamed.htm). But such trick will allows to display only some first pages of the grid. The make jqGrid really able to display large number of rows in case of virtual scrolling (`scroll: 1`) one needs to rewrite some parts of jqGrid code.

I would suggest you better to use standard paging instead of virtual scrolling. The usage will have to use First/Previous/Next/Last buttons of the pager, but the most users who need to examine 1,000,000 rows of data can do this.

To tell the trust nobody will scroll over 1,000,000 rows. Instead of that one need provide good filtering/searching possibility. For example to use [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) and [advanced searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching). After setting the corresponding filter the filtered data can be displayed in 1 till 10 pages and such data could be really interesting to display.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Oleg. Your answer was very good and correct.

Comment: you said: "needs to rewrite some parts of jqGrid code.". Which parts of jqGrid code should be rewrite? Can you explain me further?

Comment: I added that code to jqGrid option. but just about 66,000 of 1,000,000 records displayed in the grid.

Comment: @hamed: You are welcome! Could you include an example of data which returns your server? The code of `loadComplete` which I post get *correct* number of data in `data.records`, but inform jqGrid in `jsonReader.records` about more small value. Probably you have a little other format of server data. Withe rewriting I mean to rewrite the virtual scrolling implementation at all: [populateVisible](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L963-L1017), [updatepager](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L1905-L1982) and probably some other