# Refreshing jqGrid doesn't save current page position with infinite scroll enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, pagination, jqgrid-asp.net

Example from http://www.trirand.net/demo/javascript/jqgrid/loading_data/scrollbar/index.html
Versions of Guriddo jqGrid JS: 4.7.0 and 4.7.1

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  $(function () {
    $('#jqGrid').jqGrid({
      url: 'http://trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/jsonp/getjsonp.php?callback=?&qwery=longorders',
      mtype: 'GET',
      datatype: 'json',
      page: 1,
      colNames: ['Order ID', 'Customer ID', 'Order Date', 'Freight', 'Ship Name'],
      colModel: [{
        name: 'OrderID',
        key: true,
        width: 75
      }, {
        name: 'CustomerID',
        width: 150
      }, {
        name: 'OrderDate',
        width: 150
      }, {
        name: 'Freight',
        width: 150
      }, {
        name: 'ShipName',
        width: 150
      }],
      width: 750,
      height: 250,
      rowNum: 20,
      scroll: 1, // set the scroll property to 1 to enable paging with scrollbar - virtual loading of records
      emptyrecords: 'Scroll to bottom to retrieve new page', // the message will be displayed at the bottom
      pager: '#jqGridPager'
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

When I call 2 times:

```
$('#jqGrid').trigger('reloadGrid', {
    page: 3
});
```

[first time request:](http://trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/jsonp/getjsonp.php?callback=jQuery111103447585825342685_1426667139022&qwery=longorders&_search=false&nd=1426667144479&rows=20&page=3&sidx=&sord=asc&_=1426667139024) the page param is 3 as expected.

[second time request:](http://trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/jsonp/getjsonp.php?callback=jQuery111103447585825342685_1426667139022&qwery=longorders&_search=false&nd=1426667149225&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc&_=1426667139025) the page param is 1 !?

The same problems I see at refresh button with refreshstate: 'current', It doesn't work at all.

Comment: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/690

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I can confirm the bug. It exits in more old versions of jqGrid too (for example in jqGrid 4.6). The reason is in the following lines (see [the lines of the source code](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L2846-L2851))

```js
if (ts.grid.prevRowHeight && ts.p.scroll) {
    delete ts.p.lastpage;
    ts.grid.populateVisible();
} else {
    ts.grid.populate();
}
```

jqGrid have `undefined` value of `ts.grid.prevRowHeight` on the first reload of the grid and the set `ts.grid.prevRowHeight` to `22` (22px is the height of row). So the next (the second) reload of the grid will use `populateVisible` instead of `populate`. The function `populateVisible` uses current scrolling position (`scrollTop` of `bDiv`) only and it *ignores* `page` parameter of the grid.

Thus I can suggest you multiple solution of the problem: If you have to use specific old version of jqGrid (like if you have to use jqGrid 4.7) then you can use the following code as workaround:

```js
$('#jqGrid')[0].grid.prevRowHeight = undefined; // workaround!!
$('#jqGrid').trigger('reloadGrid', {
    page: 3
});
```

Alternatively you can fix the code of `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` for example to the following

```js
if (ts.grid.prevRowHeight && ts.p.scroll && opts.page === undefined) {
    delete ts.p.lastpage;
    ts.grid.populateVisible();
} else {
    ts.grid.populate();
}
```

One more option which I can suggest you: you can load the current version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) from github. It's my fork of jqGrid which is based on jqGrid 4.7 and which contains many enhancements (see [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and the [readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)). I posted just now [the corresponding fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/e5348d56fbbc9a7036303dbf369bd9a66c980c14).

Comment: Yeah, i saw, that problems in this block of code, but I have little dissapointed about two different functions and don't touch them, but I maybe use the first variant on days and give you feedback

Comment: @AuthorProxy: I personally don't like the current implementation of virtual scrolling in jqGrid and I don't recommend other to use it if it's not *really required*. I wanted to rewrite the implementation, but I didn't fond enough time for it. About the functions: `populateVisible` will be used only in case of virtual scrolling. One more important part of virtual scrolling can be found in [updatepager](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L1913-L1927). The setting of `.css({height : height})` will **not work for large number of rows**.

Comment: @AuthorProxy: Read [the old post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/virtual-scrolling-in-ie-cand-display-more-as-about-66700-rows), [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28255394/315935) or just try to display the data returned from `http://trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/jsonp/getjsonp.php?qwery=longorders` in IE. You will see wrong position of scroll bar. Only in Chrome you will have no problem.

Comment: So, what do you recommend for me @Oleg? Switch to free jqGrid if i need It on production? Why you don't work in collaboration with official team on github?

Comment: @AuthorProxy: what you mean under "official team on github"? Do you mean Tony Tomov and commercial product [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/)? Tony suggested me to join to Guriddo at the middle of December 2014, but we could find the conditions satisfied for both sides. So I started *free* fork and implemented many new features during 2 Months only. You can decide yourself whether to purchase Guriddo jqGrid JS or to use free jqGrid under MIT/GPL-licences. I recommend to read [the info](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/646#issuecomment-74786737) about validity of licence change.

Comment: So @Oleg, as I understand from 4.7.1 I can't use It anymore at production projects? Maybe today or next work day I will try to migrate to your fork, do you plan in future any docs and sample pages? Github readme not much comfortable to learn new features Could you check [this bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162609/jqgrid-scroll-bug-with-big-rows) (scrolling again, the same problems from other side).

Comment: @AuthorProxy: You can use jqGrid 4.7.1 in production only after additional the payment to trirand/guriddo. Yes, of cause I plan to create more documentation! I created some pages in [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) which is currently opened for writing for everybody. So you can modify the text or add new pages some. I plan to create documentation [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/) or [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/jqGrid/). You should understand that I have to earn money for me and my family and I have currently not enough time for free jqGrid.